# Alpine - "From address not one of your addresses"

Tags: command-line, email

I just installed Alpine in Ubuntu, and I've configured it with iCloud. It receives messages well, but when I try to send, I get this error message:

> From address is not one of your addresses.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I've searched all over the internet, but I have not found a fix yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by having an incorrect return address. It can be fixed by pressing: <kbd>m</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>, then scrolling (or using whereis) to find "Customized Headers".

From there, add something like this: `From:  Jim Bob <jimbob123@mailserver.org>` (replace the name and email with the correct ones).

That should fix your problem.

Source: [The Often-Useful Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Alpine)

Comment: @DanielDybing click the checkmark to accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: OK, thank you. I'm quite new to the functions of these sites :-)

Comment: @DanielDybing I'd actually commend you on the quality of your first post! Keep it up!